# How to prove in a graph $G$, its incidence matrix $A$ is totally unimodular if and only if $G$ is a bipartite graph?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, reference-request, total-unimodularity

I'm learning network and transportation model. The question is *not* from my homework. I'm just curious about:

> In a graph $G$, its incidence matrix $A$ is totally unimodular if and only if $G$ is a bipartite graph.

Could anyone good at proving give a simple provement?

OR

Could anyone provide some related materials?

Comment: Most books with "integer programming" in their title will have a proof of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you refer to undirected graphs, as the (node-arc-) incidence matrix of a directed graph is always totally unimodular.

Anyways, you'll find a nice proof for your question right at [the first hit on Google](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~marco/Teaching/Fall2009/DM204/Slides/TUM-lau.pdf) after querying for "incidence matrix bipartite".