# Assume that $G$ is bipartite. Prove that all vertices of $Q_G$ are integral

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, total-unimodularity

Given $G=(V,E)$, let $\mathbb{R}^V$ be the set of all real vectors $x=(x_v)_{v\in V}$ where each component $x_v$ corresponds to a vertex $v\in V$. Let $Q_G$ be defined
$$Q_G:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^V\;|\;x_u+x_v\geq1\text{ for all }\{u,v\}\in E\text{ and } x_v\geq0\text{ for all }v\in V\}$$

**My Thinking**

We know that if we can show that the matrix $A$ representing the constraints of our graph, is totally unimodular, then all vertices in $Q_G$ are integral.

Let's consider a simple graph (The picture below also includes the criteria for being totally unimodular)
[image]

In this simple example, we can see that it the statement we are trying to prove is true. But I am having trouble coming up with a formal proof for this.

**Edit**

I made a mistake on satisfying the criteria for (i). But we can always use row operations to get rid of the extra non-zero values in $B$ so it still holds that $A$ is totally unimodular. For example, adding rows 5 and 6 to rows 1,2, and 3 appropriately will allow us to satisfy the criteria for $B$ without messing with $C$ or $D$.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236385/how-to-prove-in-a-graph-g-its-incidence-matrix-a-is-totally-unimodular-if-a